# React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, set

the bellow component is for testing how to update a set with useState. The error occurs at **state.has(num)**
The state variable from useState is a set and has is a set build-in function. Why this error happens?

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(new Set());

  console.log(typeof state);

  function clickHandler(num) { 
    if (!state.has(num)) {
      setState(prevState => {
        return setState(new Set(prevState).add(num))
      })
    } else { 
      setState((prevState) => {
        return setState(new Set(prevState).delete(num));
      });
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler(1)}>1</button>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler(2)}>2</button>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler(3)}>3</button>

      { state}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` returns `undefined`

Remove `setState` from callback of `setState`

```
function clickHandler(num) { 
    if (!state.has(num)) {
      setState(prevState => {
        const set = new Set(prevState)
        set.add(num)
        return set
      })
    } else { 
      setState((prevState) => {
        const set = new Set(prevState)
        set.delete(num);
        return set
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is correct. But if you're using a Set value for useState then `setState` is not required. can directly mutate the state value like `state.add(num)`

Comment: Mutating a state is always a bad idea. It would be better to store this set in ref

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works with one modification. The delete function returns boolean. So you have to return the prevState in else block otherwise the state becomes boolean.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState(0);
  const previousValue = useRef(null);
  console.log(typeof stateValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    previousValue.current = stateValue;
  }, [stateValue]);

  function clickHandler(num) {
    setStateValue(num);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler(1)}>1</button>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler(2)}>2</button>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler(3)}>3</button>
      <br />
      <h5>number: {stateValue}</h5>
      <h5>previous number: {previousValue.current}</h5>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

best of luck :)